# Podcasts app on macOS keeps asking me to sign in

Tags: macos, bug, podcasts, monterey

No matter how many times I try signing in or click cancel, the pop-up keeps reappearing with no way to finally get rid of it and to keep it from coming back permanently. Is anyone else having this problem and possibly knows how to fix it? It's an extremely annoying bug. I'm on macOS 12.0.1.